# insmod: ERROR: could not insert module rtl8723be.ko: Unknown symbol in module

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, x86-64, inline-assembly

Using kernel 3.17.2 , I'm trying to compile & insert the latest rtl8723be driver into the kernel, but having difficulty.

I downloaded the driver from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/ and compiled it:

```
cd rtlwifi_new
make install
```

That compiles and copies the driver to the /kernel/drivers directory

I try to insert the module:

```
cd /lib/modules/3.17.2.../kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/
insmod rtl8723be.ko
```

.. and I get the following error:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module rtl8723be.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a problem with the driver itself? I'm vaguely familiar with kernel module makefiles, so I could definitely have a shot at debugging this problem myself if it's something related to my system.

Comment: did u try ""sudo insmod rtl8723be.ko" ??

Comment: try doing 'modinfo' on the rtl8723be.ko and check the depends section and use 'lsmod' to see if the dependencies are loaded. Otherway to do is to use 'modprobe' as since 'make install' seems to be calling 'depmod -a'. (use modprobe rtl8723be)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check the output of dmesg for the missing symbol and next check you kernel source if that symbol is exported.